# Change format on JButton from getSource

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

I have the following code:

```
public class LetterListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e.getActionCommand());
        e.getSource();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to set the opacity of the button after it is pressed, i.e. you click on a letter and it turns opaque. I can't think of how to implement this. Ideally I could use `e.getSource.setOpaque(true)` however this doesn't seem to be an option. I am also new to using Swing.

I initialised my `JPanel` like this, so each button is not stored in a variable.

```
JPanel letters = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,3));
for (String letter:letterArr){
    JButton button =new JButton(letter);
    LetterListener letterListener=new LetterListener();
    button.addActionListener(letterListener);
    button.setOpaque(false);
    letters.add(button);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionEvent extends from EventObject, per [the relevant API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource()), `ActionEvent#getSource()` returns Object type, and so you can't make JButton method calls on a variable of this type. To do what you want you must cast the variable to JButton type -- with all the usual warnings/caveats/provisos about the dangers of casting.

So change

```
e.getSource.setOpaque(true);
```

to:

```
((JButton) e.getSource).setOpaque(true);
```

But again I can't stress enough that whenever casting you'd better be absolutely sure that the cast is to correct type.